# Azure AD B2C OAuth2 how to refresh access token silently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, access-token, azure-ad-b2c

We are using **Azure AD B2C** to authenticate our users in an ASP.NET MVC application with **OWIN** (Microsoft.Owin.Security).

We are trying to find a way to refresh silently the access token (access_token), to avoid the multiple AJAX calls we are doing to fail. Most of them are fired automatically by the components we use (DevExpress) through callbacks, so we have very little control over them.
One solution we found is the one described by Vittorio Bertocci on his blog : http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/

**AccountController.cs**

```
public void ForcedSignIn()
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri = "/Account/AfterForcedSignIn"}, "OUR_B2C_SIGNIN_POLICY_ID");
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
          @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
          {
            <text>
              var renewUrl = "/Account/ForcedSignIn";
              var element = document.getElementById("renewSession");
              console.log("sending request to: " + renewUrl);
              element.src = renewUrl;
            </text>
          }
        },
        1000 * 20
      );
</script>

<body>
<iframe id="renewSession" style="height: 600px; width: 600px;"></iframe>
```

**AfterForcedSignIn.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
```

However, the call to https://login.microsoftonline.com is failing because it can’t be embedded in an iFrame (even if we specify “prompt” parameter to “none”).
[image: call fail]

See the message we get in Edge for example :
[image: edge iframe error]

Is there a way to avoid this issue (are we missing a parameter when calling the login page, or something else) ? Or is it another solution that exists ?

Thanks,
Léo

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSAL they have an AzquireTokenSilently method that you could use to refresh the user

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet